# https://livenation-test.apigee.net/mfxapi-tpi/events?apikey=LhNuq4GM6t7PGCzWAqkLY8W0zDbGvQ00&domain_ids=unitedkingdom&lang=en-us&query=Music Events

Tags: java, xml-parsing

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://livenation-test.apigee.net/mfxapi-tpi/events?apikey=LhNuq4GM6t7PGCzWAqkLY8W0zDbGvQ00&domain_ids=unitedkingdom&lang=en-us&query=Music Events
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at TicketMaster.readingXMlFiles(TicketMaster.java:69)
    at TicketMaster.main(TicketMaster.java:20)
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: And add a readable title.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you need to encode the space for the query parameter.

`&query=Music Events` should be `&query=Music%20Events`

**Full URL**

`https://livenation-test.apigee.net/mfxapi-tpi/events?apikey=LhNuq4GM6t7PGCzWAqkLY8W0zDbGvQ00&domain_ids=unitedkingdom&lang=en-us&query=Music%20Events`

[image: XML Response]